# Providing a local package repository on a web server

Tags: miktex, repositories

We have some problems with installing TEX packages due to firewalls and strict IT-regulations in our organization, and I'm trying to overcome some of the issues by offering the necessary MiKTeX packages on a repository hosted on a web server inside the firewall.

I have downloaded the full set of MiKTeX packages using the MiKTeX 2.9 Net Installer and copied these over to my web server.
After some research I also managed to specify the address for this web server to be the default package repository from the command line (mpm --set-repository="http://mylocallyhostedwebserver/tex").

When I open MiKTeX package manager I can see all the available packages, but when I try to install them, I get the following error: "The remote package repository is not registered. You have to choose another repository"

If I copy the same repository to a local folder on my computer and specify this folder as the package repository, the package install works fine.

Any ideas how I can make this work on the web server?

Comment: Imho it is not possible, the list of remote repositories is managed by Christian Schenk. You could try a feature request.

Comment: [Perhaps this will help ?](http://dante.ctan.org/mirroring.html)